# Grunt Typescript can't find angular core

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, typescript, npm, angular

**Question**

Why cant my Grunt Typescript compiler find the angular core?

I guess it has something to do with the paths so the compiler cant find the libs in the node_modules directory.

**Error**

> > typescript/add.component.ts(1,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/core'.

**Setup**

*Gruntfile.js Task*

```
typescript: {
    all: {
        src: ['typescript/**/*.ts'],
        dest: 'javascript/frontend',
        options: {
            target: "es5",
            module: "system",
            moduleResolution: "node",
            emitDecoratorMetadata: true,
            experimentalDecorators: true,
            removeComments: false,
            noImplicitAny: false
        }
}
```

*typescript/add.component.ts*

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'mytest',
    template: '<h1>test</h1>'
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

*node_modules*

- Includes angular2
- Includes typescript

Filepaths

```
app -- node_modules
    -- typescript
         -- app.component.ts
    -- Gruntfile.js
    -- package.json
```

**Used libs/frameworks/tutorials**

- Grunt Typescript [Github](https://github.com/k-maru/grunt-typescript)
- Angular2 [5min Quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html#!#tsconfig)

Comment: I'm an Angular2 n00b but most the examples I see use Gulp.  We are currently looking at Webpack for our builds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just now I had the same exact problem. Running grunt in verbose mode showed the content of the ts config file it generated from the grunt config. Looking more closely, this revealed that the moduleResolution option isn't used at all. But, on the other hand, it wasn't described either on the official grunt-typescript page.

Anyway, long story short: I've used the [grunt-ts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-ts) package instead and everything worked out well! I've posted my config below for your convenience :-)

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({
    ts: {
      base: {
        src: ['src/**/*.ts'],
        dest: 'dist',
        options: {
          module: 'system', 
          moduleResolution: 'node',
          target: 'es5',
          experimentalDecorators: true,
          emitDecoratorMetadata: true,
          noImplicitAny: false
        }
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-ts');


  grunt.registerTask('default', ['ts']);
};
```

Comment: Ty. Will give it a try today.

Comment: When I run 'tsc' command it works fine but using the same config as you when I run grunt I get stuff like this: `app/main.ts(1,1): error TS6053: File '/Users/jbleach/workspaces/nox/noxApp/WebContent/app/node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts' not found.
node_modules/angular2/platform/browser.d.ts(77,90): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/angular2/src/common/pipes/async_pipe.d.ts(25,38): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/angular2/src/core/application_ref.d.ts(83,60): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.`